# Can't replace empty spaces around &nsbp; tags

Tags: javascript

Objective: trying to replace the space before `&nbsp;` in this string with ''. I can replace the first instance but trying to replace it globally does not work.

```
var str = ' &nbsp;'

str.replace(/' '/g, ''); // does not work. 
str.replace(' ', ''); // works.
```

Curiously,

```
str.replace(/' &nbsp;'/g, ''); // does not work
str.replace(' &nbsp;', ''); // does not work.
```

Any ideas? What is the character before the `&nbsp`?

Some more ideas: 
str.split('') returns [" ", "&", "n", "b", "s", "p", ";"]
str.indexOf(' ') returns 0

Comment: hey so a workaround if you want to call it that is that str.replace(" ", '') works. Why doesn't single quotes work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the regular expression version of `replace`, you don't need to surround your search string with single quotes - it's instead defined by the starting and ending `/`.  This is fine:

```
var str = ' &nbsp;'
str.replace(/ /g, '');
```

When you use `/' '/g`, you're actually asking it to search for `' '`, ie including the single quotes, which aren't in the string you're searching.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enclose the regular expression with quotes, then use following format:

```
var expr = new RegExp('expression');
str = str.replace(expr,replace_str);
```